# Validate that NUnit's ITestEventListener within Jenkins Pipeline for a netcoreapp3.1 assembly is called

Tags: testing, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline, nunit

Locally, I have successfully implemented the interface `ITestEventListener` within a C# netcoreapp3.1 csproj. However, when the tests are an within a Jenkins Pipeline, things appear to not be working(?).

I am using version 3.12.0 of NUnit.Engine.

By locally I am referring to using 1) Visual Studio Version 16.9.2 to run the tests and 2) command line `dotnet test -c devint --test-adapter-path:. --logger:nunit` to run the tests. I am getting successful test runs.

Success is my `[Extension]public class ReportTestListener : ITestEventListener {...}` generates an html file. I am to see the html file is created locally whereas from the Jenkins Pipeline the html file is not generated.

Within the Jenkins Pipeline, I am using the command `sh "dotnet test -c ${env.TARGET_ENV} --test-adapter-path:. --logger:nunit"` where `env.TARGET_ENV` resolves to `devint`. I know tests successfully run within the Jenkins Pipeline since the NUnit test results file is generated/published.

What I am not sure of is how to test/validate that the `ReportTestListener` is being called within the Jenkins Pipeline. I know that testing frameworks such as NUnit uses refection to identify test classes and methods. I am presuming that also happens with my implementation of  `[Extension]public class ReportTestListener : ITestEventListener {...}`. Ideas/Suggestions on how to validate that `ITestEventListener`'s method `void OnTestEvent(string report)` is being called besides writing out to disk?

Answer (score 0):

Changed file writing text path to use `/` instead of `\`.